# Is it possible to pull users which were registered to firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-authentication

In Firebase console in Authentication tab we have tab "Users" where our users were previously registered. It is possible somehow to pull these users via API? I couldn't find a way to do it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [API to read all the users from Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) is available in the Firebase Admin SDK. There is no C# version of the Admin SDK at the moment through.

The best I can think of is to put the required functionality into Cloud Functions, and then call those from C#. Just be certain to secure the end point in that case, since an ability to list all users of an app is going to be very appealing to bad actors.

Comment: Thank you, Frank to your answer! It it exactly what I was looking for.